# Android studio gradle build failed with update

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated android studio to version 3.2. When I tried running my old project, I got the following message for my old project while running grade build:

```
"The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher.
```

Project '4thtry' is using version 1.2.50."  How to rectify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your root `Build.gradle` and update the `Kotlin`.

**(Better idea)**: Add the latest version: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'` (or above of `1.2.50`) instead of `1.2.50` then rebuild the project.

So we'll have;

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
..
}
dependencies {
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
...
}
```

Comment: Why can’t Android Studio do this step automatically?

Comment: That's a good question. Mostly, it's up to developer which can manage the versions by it's own development and it's approaches. But, looking at the `Settings - Kotlin Compiler` and there were no options to add Kotlin version in there. Probably, there will be an option to set such versions automatically in future in the mentioned location.