# Why After update android gradle i got error?

Tags: android, gradle

after update my gradle in android studio i got error

Why my code is not working?

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

I tried 1.3.0 but still got this error

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.3.0

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Conflict these versions.

Comment: What is the version of `kotlin_version`?

Comment: please add project gradle file

Comment: you didn't show any errors.

Comment: edit the question and add it to question.  It clearly says that `The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher. The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: root project 'Chunter' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.30`. Which literally means that you have to use `1.3.0` or higher

Comment: you need to change it somewhere else. But since you ignore requests to post your full `build.gradle` file, good luck fixing it on your own. It also could be in the root project build.gradle

Comment: Check this answer using version 1.3.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52579000/7746134

Comment: Connect to the internet, Go to settings and update your gradle one more time solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.3.0

`kotlin-stdlib-jre7` has been deprecated. Please use `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` instead.

Comment: Thank you. can you please help me with this warning? WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

Comment: If you've already changed the `compile` dependencies you have in your build.gradles, have a look at your gradle plugins - one of them might be still injecting `compile` depenencies.